# How to open up the developer tools panel with pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web, web-applications, contextmenu, developer-tools

I'm currently working on a context menu for a web app, and one of the options is inspect, but I searched everywhere and there's nothing about opening up the dev tools panel with only JavaScript. Is there a way to do that?

I tried `window.inpect()` but obviously it isn't a function.

Comment: It's not possible to do this.